# Nokia Maps (v2.2): mousedown/mouseup issue

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to create a rectangle on map with single mouse move (like in Photoshop, GIMP etc).
I removed behaviour component and added listeners:

```
map.addListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);              
map.addListener("mousedown", onDragStart);              
map.addListener("mouseup", onDragEnd);
```

But when I press left mouse button and then move mouse over the map, no "mouse move" event occurs.
Also, when I release button, no "mouse up" event occurs.

But, when I click left mouse buttons, both "mouse down" and "mouse up" events occurs simultaneously.

Is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?234571-Problem-with-mousedown-mouseup-events&p=889270#post889270